# Inline and Block LaTeX?

Tags: support

How do I show LaTeX renders in Tex.SE?

`$\dfrac{1}{2}$` and `$$\dfrac{1}{2}$$` seem to work for other StackExchange, but not Tex StackExchange. Any clue why?

I would guess LaTeX rendering to be most important for the Tex StackExchange, so I'm assuming there's some other way to render LaTeX in questions and answers. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've marked as a dupe: I suspect you didn't know the terms to search for. Briefly, the 'LaTeX' you see in web pages is rendered by MathJaX, which is _not_ TeX but parses a modified subset of the math mode syntax. Here, we want to see _actual_ TeX output if there is a need to have an image at all.